# Create an array from a hash with each_with_index

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

What I want to do is to create a Hash so that it looks like:

```
{1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => c}
```

I tried to do that:

```
Hash[arr.each_with_index.map { |item, i|  [i => item] }]
```

but didn't get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_with_index` returns the original receiver. In order to get something different from the original receiver, `map` is necessary anyway. So there is no need of an extra step using `each` or `each_with_index`. Also, `with_index` optionally takes the initial index.

```
Hash[arr.map.with_index(1){|item, i| [i, item]}]
# => {1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => c}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on why you think using `map.with_index(1)` is better that `each_with_index`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Hash[]` takes an array of arrays as argument. So you need to use `[i, item]` instead of `[i => item]`

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
Hash[arr.each_with_index.map{|item, i| [i+1, item] }]
#=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```

Just for clarification: `[i => item]` is the same as writing `[{i => item}]` so you really produced an array of arrays that in turn contained a single hash each.

I also added a `+1` to the index so the hash keys start at `1` as you requested. If you don't care or if you want to start at `0`, just leave that off.

Comment: Your code actually produce the hash `{0=>"a", 1=>"b", 2=>"c"}`.

Comment: That's right sorry for that... Copy paste mistake. Corrected now.

Comment: you should get *+1*.. And I did.. Nice explanation... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
p Hash[arr.map.with_index(1){|i,j| [j,i]}]
# >> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```